# Change Cursor as Feedback in DragDrop VB.NET 2010

Tags: vb.net, drag-and-drop, mouse-cursor

Working on a DragDrop application.  I have a class object (built as an object) which has a GroupBox that is enabled for DragDrop.

In the class I have set it up so that the cursor will change when it enters the groupbox, leaves the groupbox, mouse is down within the groupbox and drag/drop is working.  I also set up a label in the class object and changed the text in that label as well.  Basically, the text changes in the label as expected including 'FEEDBACK' appearing when I am dragging the object BUT the cursor stays stubbornly as a pointer.  This is tghe state of affairs either when I debug the class or when, after I build the class, it is run as part of the main program.

Here are the subs set up in the class.

```
Private Sub GroupBoxSourceMouseDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles GroupBoxSource.MouseDown
    GroupBoxSource.DoDragDrop(GroupBoxSource.Text, DragDropEffects.Copy)
    lbl1.Text = "DOWN"
End Sub

Private Sub GroupBoxSourceMouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e  AsSystem.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles GroupBoxSource.MouseMove
    If bolDragDropMouseDown Then
        ' Initiate dragging.
        'GroupBoxSource.DoDragDrop(GroupBoxSource.Text, DragDropEffects.Copy)
    End If
    bolDragDropMouseDown = False
    lbl1.Text = "MOVE"
End Sub

Private Sub GroupBoxSourceMouseEnter(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles GroupBoxSource.MouseEnter
    Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current = Cursors.Hand
    lbl1.Text = "ENTER"
End Sub

Private Sub GroupBoxSourceMouseLeave(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles GroupBoxSource.MouseLeave
    Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current = Cursors.Arrow
    lbl1.Text = "LEAVE"
End Sub

Private Sub GroupBoxSourceDragDropFeedback(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GiveFeedbackEventArgs) Handles GroupBoxSource.GiveFeedback
    Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current = Cursors.SizeAll
    lbl1.Text = "FEEDBACK"
End Sub
```

Now for the unusual stage.  I decided to change the cursor during FormLoad of the main program (which has the class object defined on the form) to a hand and nothing changed.  In desperation I set up a 1mS timer and coded that to change the cursor to a hand and sure enough the cursor is now a hand but momentarity flicks back to a pointer when I move the cursor so it looks as if something else is causing the cursor to revert to its default value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To easily change the cursor, click on the form and bring up the properties. Then go to Cursor and change it to whatever you want.

Comment: Hi, been away for a while.  eventually got the Drag/Drop to work and used an 'ico' cursor.  for anyone else trying to do it, I used a frreware irfanview which converts from just about any format to ico.  Then I used         customCursor = New Cursor(prmCursorFile)

Answer (score 3):

You have to set e.UseDefaultCursor = False in your GiveFeedback event handler to make your cursor change visible.  Without it, drag and drop always uses the default cursors.

The cursor you get when the mouse hovers a control is set by the Control.Cursor property.  Changing the Cursor.Current property has no effect, the property causes the cursor to change back instantly when you move the mouse.

Comment: great.  That sorted it out,  much appreciated.

Comment: @Hans Passant, your suggestion works, but how do you change cursor back to default after Drop ?